# Extract number from text string

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to extrapolate all the numbers inside a text string (based on a condition) and if the numbers are separated by a text they should be separated too. Below an example to better understand since the problem it's very complex

#### Example

```
  INPUT                                             OUTPUT1     OUTPUT2

1 500ML BIA BINGWA SORGHUM                          1           500
2 CLUB 07 VODKA LEMON 24X330ML                      24          330
3 375ML EAGLE LAGER REGULAR RB 375X20ML             20          375
4 KONYAGI GIN 1X500ML                               1           500
5 SAFARI LAGER NRB 24x330 LOCAL                     24          330
```

*Notes*

- In row 1 the `OUTPUT1 = 1` even there is no `1x500ML` but only `500ML`
- Row 3 have reverse order, instead of `20x375ML` -> `375x20ML` (*I think that this can be overcomed with "put smallest in `OUTPUT1` and Largest in `OUTPUT2`*)
- Row 5 doesn't have `ML` so the recognition should be made by the `x` used as separator

both formula and VBA approaches are fine.

Comment: extrapolate:  "to predict by projecting past experience or known data"  I don't think that's the word you want ? I'm guessing you want just "extract" ?  It kind of changes the question ... ;)

Comment: How much data?  (Rekey it)  Program would take too long to write and would still be wrong.

Comment: @Ditto: Yes, I just want to extract.

Comment: @xQbert: like 200 records but I'd like something automatic to be reusable in time...

Comment: Your formula implied by the results you seek is not clear. Also, this is not a 'code for me' site, it is for specific Q&A. Have you attempted this? What problems did you have?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon What i'm seeking here some hints for the approach. I think that the formula it's clear. You see the input and the outputs. Unfortunately I don't know where to start since it's not a matter of "i do not know the code by I know how to do it". Anyway I saw that the question isn't likable so i'll keep the problem for me and i will delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is error prone but it does give you a starting point to spot check the 200

Using excel formula's you could do something like this; but each record would still have to be spot checked.  For example if a product has an X in the name beyond the 24x330 then it would error or provide wrong values.  The data is just too unstable to generate a true program to do this and account for all possibilities.  We're not saying it can't be done, simply saying the time would be better spent manually doing it.

As you can see I couldn't easily handle row 3:

Formula for E:
=IFERROR(MID(B1,FIND("X",UPPER(B1))-2,2),1)*1

Formula for F:
=MID(B1,IF(FIND("ML",UPPER(B1))<6,1,FIND("ML",UPPER(B1))-3),3)

[image]